# Chrome behaviour with css class

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, background-image

The issue is pretty strange and I haven't encountered something like this until now.
Here are 2 CSS classes

```
.header {
  background-image: url('pictures/header.png');
  height:99px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  display:block;
  z-index:10;
}
.advertise_tab {
  background-image: url('pictures/advertise_span.png');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:90px;
  left:0px;
  display:block;
  z-index:1;
 }
```

My problem comes with the second class in Chrome. In IE and Firefox it works fine, but in Chrome `.advertise_tab` doesn't have background. I tried with and without quotes and there is no change. The funny thing is that `.header` works just fine and I don't see the difference between the two which might cause this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what version of chrome you running?

Comment: Version 27.0.1453.110 m

Comment: Here's a fiddle seems to be working fine? http://jsfiddle.net/QKCbE/

Comment: Do you have an adblocker installed? These can stop divs (or images) with certain keywords in the class- or filename from appearing. I've fallen foul of this myself before.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Especially one that indicates the image resource wasn't loaded properly?

Comment: I tried your .advertise_tab in chrome it just worked fine.

Comment: I have noticed you are absolutely positioning everything, have you absolutely positioned something on top of `.advertise_tab`?

Comment: Have you checked in the dev tools to see what styles are being applied? And also whether the image is being downloaded at all?

Comment: @MassivePenguin Thank you very much!!! It was AdBlocker i had installed in chrome, I changed the name and it worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from AdBlocker I had installed in Chrome. Many thanks to @MassivePenguin, for pointing that!

Comment: Yes, I was also facing similar problem. not in Chrome but in FF where I have installed adblock+. I have set an image with name advt.jpg as a background and image didn't appear. Struggled for hours to find the cause. Finally I found the cause by disabling all adons. Later then, I stopped using names with ad, ads advt, advertisement etc. for images, classes, IDs etc....

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an example of the `HTML` markup you're using with these styles?

I've created a jsfiddle with some small changes to the formatting of the `CSS`, and some images from [lorempixel](http://lorempixel.com) and it seems to work in Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/j9gYA/

HTML

```
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="advertise_tab">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/99');
    height: 99px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
.advertise_tab {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/500');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And a screenshot of the code/result in case jsfiddle is down:

http://uk.omg.li/Pf53/by%20default%202013-06-14%20at%2010.29.54.png

So I can't think what, in the `CSS`, would be causing any problems. Perhaps there's a problem with your `advertise_span.png` image, or Chrome didn't load it correctly in to cache?

Try doing a shift+reload, or clearing your browser cache.